# Could not find a part of the path 'D:\~\images\Emblem.JPG'

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, controls

I am getting the following error while i try to embed a itexsharp logo

Could not find a part of the path 'D:\~\images\Emblem.JPG'.

This is the function which is calling

i have commented the working line and not working line

```
   private iTextSharp.text.Image CreateAndSetLogo()
          {
              string ImgPath = "D:\\Projects\\Project\\ASPX\\images\\Emblem.JPG"; //Working 

              Not working // string ImgPath = "~/images/Emblem.JPG"; 

              iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ImgPath);

              logo.ScaleToFit(100, 100);
              logo.SetAbsolutePosition(100f, 680f);
              return logo;
          }
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 4):

For the non working string you should call `Server.MapPath(...)` to get the absolute path of your relative string.

Answer (score 0):

I thought using the tilde as a shorthand for the user's home directory was a Unix thing.  Are you sure it's supported under Windows?  I just tried "cd ~" at a Win7 command prompt and got the error "The system could not find the path specified".